# executing pm2 list linux commands from java code

Tags: java, linux, server, server-monitoring

I am exectuing linux commands from java code using priced8and processbuilder class i am able to execute free,df,sar commands so basically im running application using pm2 so in pm2  im when application starts im able to execute linux commands but not only pm2 list, it executes but return null or empty

Tried process,processbuilder, sh file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.